# Using Fourier transform to solve the wave equation with friction

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

How do I solve this wave equation with friction using Fourier transform?
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
u_{tt} - \alpha u_{t} = c^2u_{xx} & \quad -\infty< x< \infty , t>0, \\
\quad u(x,0) = \phi(x), \\
\quad u_t(x,0) = \psi(x). 
\end{array} 
\right. $$

where $\alpha, \beta, c \in  \mathbb{R}$ are constants?

I think I understand that for this problem, I need to let $F(k,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t)e^{-ikx}\,dx$

Then, by transforming the equation I think it becomes...
$F(k,t)= A(k)\cos(kct)+B(k)\sin(kct)$

Comment: You need to explain what steps you've taken on this problem.

Comment: Take a FT ($\hat{u} = \int u(x)e^{ikx}{\rm d}x$) wrt $x$ to get an ODE for $\hat{u}$ given by $\hat{u}_{tt} - \alpha \hat{u}_t = -k^2c^2 \hat{u}$ and where $\hat{u}(k,t=0) = \hat{\phi}(k)$ and $\hat{u}_t(k,t=0) = \hat{\psi}(k)$. Write down solution in terms of inverse FT.

Comment: Please note my edits to the question including the proper ways to write $\sin$ and $\cos.$ And your use of \mbox{} was weird and I deleted it.

Comment: Solution you can find in the book:https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Differential-Equations-Engineers-Scientists/dp/1584882999/ref=pd_sbs_14_1?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=1584882999&pd_rd_r=5E3FZ83CY30Q3F2BCPXX&pd_rd_w=W75cd&pd_rd_wg=T0JsV&psc=1&refRID=5E3FZ83CY30Q3F2BCPXX example `4.4.1.3`